# Too many dots in Safari password fields

Tags: safari, internationalization, password

Safari 12.0.1 (14606.2.104.1.1) / macOS Mojave 10.14.1 (18B75) / both Mac Mini late 2018 and macBookAir late 2018.

Each time I type a character in a password field, instead of being displayed as a unique dot, it generates lots of dots after a micro-delay. I know it's hard to believe, but in the first example below, I have actually typed one single character; in the second one, two characters:

[image: I have typed ONE character]

[image: I have typed TWO characters]

- Same behavior on any web page with a password field.
- Safari only. No problem on Chrome or Firefox.
- Asking 1Password to fill in the field works. BTW, I thought 1Password was the culprit, but disabling its extension had no effect.
- Deleting `type="password"` with Safari's inspector makes the problem disappear, but of course that reveals the typed characters.

So I am left scratching my head. Any lead?

Comment: Does it really matter? Is your password being correctly sent to the server, or is an incorrect string being generated?

Comment: It's the incorrect string which was generated. For instance, if the shortcut was defined as "foobar ", and my password was "love123" (oops!), the password actually sent to the site was "foobar foobar foobar ... foobar".

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Found it, my fault. I had recently defined a system-wide shortcut associating the symbol "•" to another string. Worst idea ever! As soon as a dot appeared, it was expanded to several characters, all replaced by dots, and so on. Since I usually use 1Password, I only hit the issue a few days after the fact.

Now there's something on the internet in case somebody makes the same mistake :)

Comment: Glad it worked out. Please mark your question as resolved.

Comment: Question can only be marked resolved after a self-answer once 2 days have passed....

Comment: I'm confused how such shortcuts can even possibly apply to a character that isn't actually _typed_, only shown on screen.

Comment: @grawity Yes, Chrome and Firefox do the right thing here.

Comment: If the field's value stays accurate, it seems like a nice mitigation against shoulder surfing. Not a really strong defense, but _just another_ defense.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia - I've used software that, if I type `hunter2` in the password field, I get an almost random number of "dots" showing up on screen. So typing just `h` might show `•••` then `u` may show `•`, etc...so the length of the password is *not* same as length of the obfuscated password showing on the screen.  I've always wondered why that's not more widespread.

Comment: Sorry - I only see `*******` in your first line. Seems StackExchange is filtering out your password :O

Comment: How do you define the system-wide shortcut? Is it something in the operating system or is it a program you use.

Comment: @KodosJohnson System Preferences->Keyboard->Text has options to set up arbitrary text replacements. There's also System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts, which allow you to bind arbitrary keystrokes to menu commands, and • seems to be a valid input for that. There are also third-party apps that do this, like [TypeIt4Me](https://www.ettoresoftware.com/mac-apps/typeit4me/) (with a 25+ year history on the Mac). I don't know what the OP used in particular.

Comment: @BruceWayne Linux terminals (and possibly others) do that all the time: Each time you type a character in a password, a random number of dots (between zero and none) appear on the screen.